# Formula field help, please

Tags: formula-field

I have 3 text formula fields: Field 1, Field 2 and Field 3. I want to create Field 4 formula field that checks if there is value in any of those 3 fields and give the value to Field 4.

I have tried:

IF ( NOT(ISBLANK (Field_1__c)), Field_1__c, NULL) - but the formula is too big to execute.

BLANKVALUE (Field_1__c, NULL) - but I want to be able to check all 3 and the populate Field 4 with the value

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This formula is very short. If it fails because it's too big to execute than that means that the formula in Field_1__c is at the limit of what it can contain. If you edit your question and add that formula, then someone may be able to help you improve its efficiency.

Comment: @Kasper - I was just replying below. I had to create 3 formula fields, as I had 11000+ characters formula, so they had to be split into 3. The formula fields are to generate different codes, depending on the Billing Country selected and Billing States.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you include a formula in another formula the compiled size is always at least the size of the formula you include. With formula's that big you might want to look into programming solutions (triggers) or perhaps you can do something with a process builder.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the formula above:

```
IF(
NOT(
ISBLANK(Field1__c)
), 
Field1__c, 
IF(
NOT(
ISBLANK(Field2__c)
), 
Field2__c, 
IF(
NOT(
ISBLANK(Field3__c)
), 
Field3__c, 
null
) 
) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have just tried it, but it's too big to execute, unfortunately. I should specify the field 1,2,3 formula fields have 3000+characters....

Comment: Can you detail which is the field type for those three fieds? Are they Text Area (Long)?

If the formula field won't work for you this concatenation can be performed via Process Builder as well, which can be ran every time the record is updated.

Comment: They are Formula fields

Comment: I would suggest you use Workflows in order to achieve what you want. 

I tested it and it seems to be working: Create a Workflow Rule on the object you want to have that field populated with the _"Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited"_. On the Rule Criteria you can either choose something like "1<>2" (for it to always run) or add your own criteria.

Then create a Text Area (Long) field in order to retain this value and on the Worfklow Field update paste the formula I answered you with in the first place.

Comment: Just tried it, but it doesn't update the field.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Workflow rule is active? Or can you try to update the new field with a value other than the formula in order to see if the issue is the formula or the workflow conditions?

Comment: The workflow rule is active and I have just tried to update the field with another field other than the formula and it works, so the workflow conditions work.

Comment: I've even changed the workflow to only look at one of the formula fields if it's populated, and then Field Update on the new field, still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi SSimon,

Can you confirm what you have selected for the "Blank Field Handling" option in your Formula fields? 

If you have "Treat blank fields as zeroes" then please try to either edit the formula to use BLANKVALUE instead of ISBLANK or change the "Blank Field Handling" to "Treat blank fields as null"

Comment: Hi, It is "Treat blank fields as blanks". I have amended the criteria and now it only fires the first line. If the formula field 1 gets updates, then it allocates the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help with this. I have just put all the formulas in the WR, without IF conditions and it works this way :) and it saves me extra fields. Good tip.